# How can i get responseText from AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the `responseText` from an AJAX response? Below is my code:

```
<audio controls>
    <source ng-src="{{abc}}" type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

```js
$scope.postTitle = function(a1) {
    $scope.tce = a1;
    console.log($scope.tce);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://language.cs.usm.my/synthesis/read.php',
        data: {
            'submit': 'submit',
            'malayText': $scope.tce
        }, // you can use as much as data you want to send,
        dataType: 'JSON', // so you can use the json_encode php function
        complete: function(response) {
            console.log("Posted");
            console.log(response.responseText);
            $scope.text = (response.responseText);
            $scope.url = $scope.text.substring(514, 568);
            $scope.abc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.url);
            console.log($scope.url);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what errors do you see in the browsers developer tools console

Comment: Your code should be working fine. The `complete` handler takes the jqXHR object which has a `responseText` property you can read. Your code does this. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Your code should work but If you're facing any problem using `complete`, then try `success: function(data){
            return data;
        }` after `dataType`.

Comment: @Mr.Developer — **return**?! In an asynchronous callback function?!

Comment: use `factory/service` for it instead.

Comment: The ajax call is defined inside postTitle method, is postTitle is called? Are you seeing something in the console?

Comment: @Alex are you using any other framework with this.?

Comment: I can't get {{abc}} from the ajax function, any method to get $scope.abc on HTML?

Answer (score -1):

You should not be using jQuery AJAX's response/callbacks directly to adjust your scope. Use `$http` to get the response to trigger the digest cycle.

Comment: The reason I use AJAX is because of i need to post data on server and submit it directly